# Replacing wireless routers (APs)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

So... I've landed a part time job helping out in the IT department of a small business, and I have been tasked with replacing the existing wireless routers (dlink) with new ones (Unifi AP). The software CD that came with it is somewhat confusing, so what steps do I need to take to configure them? They will need static IP adresses (going to use the ones already in use). 
Any help is welcome, thank you!

Comment: Are the devices you are replacing actually routers, or just access points? There is a significant difference between them.

Comment: Now that you ask I feel slightly stupefied. I would say access points, as they are only connected to a switch (utp cable) and they are just there to provide wireless connection to the Internet within the office.

Comment: What about the software is confusing. Have you installed it successfully and are trying to use it to access one of them?

Answer (score 0):

Have you visited the Unifi website? It looks like one uses DHCP to initialize the APs, then you will need a workstation to manage the devices: http://dl.ubnt.com/guides/UniFi/UniFi_AP_QSG.pdf

Comment: I've read the manual, the software confuses me. I don't think they use DHCP. I presume I do need a computer to configure all of them, but I just wanted to ask what is needed in the configuration, if someone has done this with thi Unifi AP before.

Answer (score 0):

We use UniFi APs where I work and they are great.

Allow me to give you a high level overview of how they work, and then I'll let Professor Youtube explain the details of getting your first AP setup.

The UniFi series from Ubiquiti Networks are strictly APs, they are not routers, and in fact, they don't have any type of web server on them at all for configurations.  This is fundamentally different than the wireless routers that you were using previously.  The UniFi APs should receive their IP address from DHCP (At least thats how we do it and its easy).

All the configuration changes, updates, usage reports, passwords, etc, are set up and maintained from the UniFi Controller software.  This is a cross platform program that is installed once, used to setup the APs and then used to make changes or view usage.  The software is not actually required to run the APs on a daily basis, but it is required to set them up initially, and to make any changes to the setup.

The most common scenario with the UniFi APs is to have each AP connected to a switch and have the UniFi Controller software also running on the same network.  The Software, once installed should prompt you to complete a setup wizard, I found this to be useful but I still had to make several changes after the wizard was completed.

For the details of setting up your First AP, I found this pretty good Youtube Video from Ubiquiti Networks.  [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdXoIi1UdEI)

Comment: It would all have been peaches and oranges if it weren't for the fact that the company doesn't use DHCP :) but I managed my way around nad got it done. Thanks anyway!